# Xcode 7.3 strange dialog box when making new project

Tags: macos, xcode7

When I start a new project in Xcode 7.3 a misaligned dialog box appears
[image]

This did not happen in Xcode 6. Can anybody confirm if this is happening on their computer as well, so I know if it is an Xcode bug or not. If it is not a bug can anything be done to make it look nicer?

Comment: Looks like a Xcode bug. You should report it to Apple.

Comment: This has been fixed in the new release. Time to update.

Comment: You are right john, I updated to Xcode 8 and the bug is not longer there.

Comment: Unfortunately upgrading to Xcode 8.0 brings new problems. When building the project it complaints about "Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed". I have no idea what this even means. It also has some issues with Signing, which 7.3 did not have. So I will go back to Xcode 7.3 and live with misaligned dialog box, until Apple has fixed the Signing issues.